# React Native scrolling animation

Tags: react-native

[image: SEE HERE]

When i scroll up and down in my FlatList, the height of the HeaderArea doesn't change it's height whatsoever! As i scroll and view items in the flatlist further down the page, the HeaderArea needs to reduce in size from `startHeaderHeight` to `endHeaderHeight`. Please help, can you spot where am i going wrong?

```
const START_HEADER_HEIGHT = (ITEM_HEIGHT/5);
const END_HEADER_HEIGHT  = (ITEM_HEIGHT/8);
const HEADER_SCROLL_DISTANCE =  START_HEADER_HEIGHT -  END_HEADER_HEIGHT;



     export default class MyClass extends Component {
        
       constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {

            columns: 3, //Columns for Grid

             /***** Animated scrolling hide header info ****/
             scrollY:  new Animated.Value(0),

      
        };

    }
           
            render() {
         
                const animatedHeaderHeight = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
                  inputRange: [0, HEADER_SCROLL_DISTANCE],
                  outputRange: [START_HEADER_HEIGHT, END_HEADER_HEIGHT],
                  extraploate: 'clamp'
                })

              return (
        
        
                 <SafeAreaView style={styles.profileContainer}> 
        
                        <View style={styles.flatStyle}> 
                          
                           <FlatList 

                            style={styles.scrollViewContent}    
                            numColumns={columns}
              
                            data={tempUserImagesArray}  //defined elsewhere

                            scrollEventThrottle={16}

                            onEndReached={()=>console.log('End reach')}
                            bounces={false}

                            onScroll={Animated.event(
                                [{nativeEvent:{contentOffset: {y: this.state.scrollY}}}],
                              
                         
                            )}
                                    keyExtractor={   (item, index) => { return index }   }
                                    renderItem=
                                           ..............
                                              />        
                                              )
                                      }} 
                                   
                           />
                         </View> 
                         <Animated.View style={[styles.infoArea, { height: animatedHeaderHeight }]}>             
                             //Plain Orange rectangle
                         </Animated.View>
                     
               </SafeAreaView>
          )
        }
        
        
        
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     profileContainer: {
          flex: 1,
        
 },
 infoArea: {
      //flex: 1,
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      backgroundColor: 'orange',
      overflow: 'hidden',
 },
 scrollViewContent: {
     marginTop: START_HEADER_HEIGHT,
     
 },
```

flatStyle: {
width: '100%',
height: START_HEADER_HEIGHT,
flex: 1
},
HeaderArea: {

```
 },
 grid: {
     flex: 1,
     flexDirection: 'column',
 },
    
 });
}
```

What I need is more like this:
[image: SEE HERE]

Comment: Try removing the SafeAreaView. I am not sure, but since the tag is responsible for always keeping the screen content below the header, I think it may be interfering with any of the header animations!

Comment: Hi, that didn't work

Comment: Please see image in OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem, you're nesting FlatList inside ScrollView, when your FlatList being render it will render the number of item base on the height of parent view and... it parent (ScrollView) have infinity height so everything in FlatList will be render at once and FlatList will not scrollable. The component you're scrolling is the ScrollView not the FlatList that is why your `onScroll` useless.

By the way, I think you're creating something like header collapsing view, header will collapse during scrollup, appear when scroll down. I've working on it recently, you can get the idea from this [article](https://medium.com/@habibridho/implementing-collapsing-toolbar-using-react-native-4a84e1718f11), if your design contain tabs. Use this [react-native-collapsible-tab-view](https://github.com/PedroBern/react-native-collapsible-tab-view), trust me, if it contain tabs, recreating the component will blow your head.

Comment: Ok, let just ignore all other issues and make your code work first. Here take a look at https://codepen.io/khuongnb/pen/poREeOG. I've edited your code by get rid of ScrollView, change `useNativeDriver` to false since the prop `height` cannot use native driver. If you do want to keep the ScrollView, wrap your FlatList into a View with fixed height like `<View style={{flex: 1, height: 500}}>`, remember to add `scrollEventThrottle={16}` to your FlatList

Comment: What is the error? have you complete your code before run?

Comment: Can you update the newest code as well? This problem happen because your FlatList item-container height is not high enough, it will reach the end when you scroll up, put 20 more images to make the scrolling work. To debug this issue, add `onEndReached={()=>console.log('End reach')}` and `bounces={false}`.

Comment: It's because the ScrollView still there and there is no limit for FlatList being render, thought you were get rid of it. Wrap your FlatList into a View, like this `<View style={{width: '100%', height: 500}}><FlatList .../> </View>`

Comment: It's hard to say, here I've edited the full code for you, you can take a look https://codepen.io/khuongnb/pen/abpydmp

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!! I've tested this and it works precisely as I expect it to. Take the bounty with pleasure :)